# Bat script to rename files

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder with many images (jpg format) imported by a smartphone, and I want to rename them in team_# where # is an increasing number. So what I want is team_1.jpg, team_2.jpg, ...

What I did is this:

```
SET /A count=1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%j in (*.jpg) do (
REN "%%j" "team_!count!.jpg"
SET /A count=count+1)
endlocal
```

but the result is quite strange. It "misses" a number! This means that for example I have team_1.jpg, team_2.jpg, ..., team_7.jpg, team_9.jpg It skips 8. And if I relaunch the script, it skips a number, but a different one.

I tried removing the underscore from the file name and everything works ok, but actually I need the underscore.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, in place of

for %%j in (*.jpg) do (

for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (

*if you* **ECHO REN...** *instead of* **REN**, *just temporarily, then batch will simply report the required rename, but not execute it. Remove the* **ECHO** *to perform the rename*

What I believe is happening is that the `ren`  is renaming something *to* team_8.jpg, then renaming team_8.jpg to team_somethingelse.jpg.

The `dir` command will build a list of `.jpg` names, *then* the `for/f` processes the list.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I changed the script in order to rename alle the files in foo_!count!.jpg. Then I put back team_!count!.jpg and everything worked perfectly. Thank you!